# Cron: Backing up log, config, website files as non-root user via SSH / Rsync

Tags: centos, backup

I'm brainstorming ways that I can begin backing up my production servers' log files, config files, website data, mysql databases, etc.... as a non-root user to a separate off-site location.

The problem is this:
For security reasons, I have the root user locked down so that root can never directly log into the production server. But in addition, the off-site physical server (in my home) is behind a dynamic IP address, so I can't do syslogging from production to backup in case my IP address changes.

What are you guys' thoughts on the best way to address this issue? 1 idea I had is this:
Create a new user, called "backups" on the server, and give this user read-only access to everything (I need to backup) with setfacl:

```
setfacl -R -m g:backups:r-x /paths/to/directories
```

Then run rsync as the user "backups" from a cron of say, every 24 hours, on the machine where all of the backups will be stored. (Of course, log files would be backed up on a different cron, of say, every 5 minutes or so...)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But in addition, the off-site physical server (in my home) is behind a
>   dynamic IP address, so I can't do syslogging from production to backup
>   in case my IP address changes.

How about the dynamic DNS and port forwarding?

> 1 idea I had is this: Create a new user, called "backups" on the
>   server, and give this user read-only access to everything (I need to
>   backup) with setfacl

You'd better consider using a restricted shell with [scponly](https://github.com/scponly/scponly/wiki) or [rssh](http://www.pizzashack.org/rssh/).

```
$ ./configure --enable-rsync-compat
$ make
$ sudo make install
# echo /usr/local/bin/scponly >> /etc/shells
# sudo usermod -s /usr/local/bin/scponly backups
```

Comment: I held off on accepting this for a while, but I'm going to go ahead and do so now. I actually already have rssh installed on the server for other user access control, so I think that this is a good idea. Even though I haven't implemented it, the dynamic DNS / port forwarding idea isn't bad either. Thanks for taking the time to respond to this.